# Getting JsonData in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

i have a json data like this

```
LearnerNotes =     (
                (
                        {
                Notes = "Neely down";
                NotesDate = "2014-10-27 13:53:47";
                NotesID = 15;
            },
                        {
                Notes = Imposition;
                NotesDate = "2014-10-27 13:22:28";
                NotesID = 14;
            }
        )
    );
    PeriodDate = "2014-11-04T10";
    PeriodID = 58127;
    PersonID = 12735;
    SubjectName = English;
    TeacherNotes = "My Learning Choices: This note contoins the some text as the learner provide for the teacher when booking it and will always be shown first";
}
```

Now i am getting only the LearnerNotes like…

```
 NSArray *notesArray=[[[jsondata valueForKey:@"LearnerNotes"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Notes"];
```

In console aim getting like this

```
notesarray (
        (
        "Neely down",
        Imposition
    )
)
```

Now i want to display it in UITableView but it is not coming only last value is coming(Imposition).
Iam new to iOS please help….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching a JSON data and build an `NSArray` with all notes keep this NSArray in some property.

Use this NSArray as data source for a `UITableView` by implementing all required `UITableViewDataSource`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html